# Why separable convolution implemented by tensorflow is slower than the normal convolution?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I have tested the speed of `separable_conv2d` and `normal conv2d` implemented in TF, it seems the only `depthwise_conv2d` is faster than the `normal conv2d` but the performance of the dw_conv2d is poor obviously.

The separable_conv2d mentioned in MobileNet, its `FLOPs` is 1/9 of the normal conv when the `kernel_size=3`, but considering the `Memory Access Cost` the separable one cannot be 9 times faster than the normal one but in my experiment, the separable one is too much slower.

I modeling the experiment like this [separable_conv2d is too slow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12132#issuecomment-395532466). In this experiment, the separable_conv2d seems faster than the normal one when the depth_multiply=1, but when I use `tf.nn` to implement it as follows:

```
IMAGE_SIZE= 512
REPEAT = 100
KERNEL_SIZE = 3
data_format = 'NCHW'
#CHANNELS_BATCH_SIZE =  2048 # channe# ls * batch_size
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"

def normal_layers(inputs, nfilter, name=''):
    with tf.variable_scope(name, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
         shape = inputs.shape.as_list()
         in_channels = shape[1]
         filter = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,
                                  shape=[KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE, 
                                   in_channels, nfilter], name='weight')
         conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input= inputs, filter=filter, strides= 
                           [1,1,1,1],padding='SAME',data_format=data_format, 
                           name='conv')
    return conv
def sep_layers(inputs, nfilter, name=''):
    with tf.variable_scope(name, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
         shape= inputs.shape.as_list()
         in_channels = shape[1]
         dw_filter=
         tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,
                         shape=[KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE, 
                         in_channels, 1], name='dw_weight')

         pw_filter = 
         tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,
                                shape=[1,1,in_channels, nfilter], 
                         name='pw_weight')          
         conv = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d_native(input=inputs,
                                              filter=dw_filter,
                                              strides=[1,1,1,1],
                                              padding='SAME',
                                              data_format=data_format)
         conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input=conv,
                             filter=pw_filter,
                             strides=[1,1,1,1],
                             padding='SAME',
                             data_format=data_format)
    return conv
```

Each layer run in `100 times`,
different from the link is I set the `batch_size` as a constant 10,
and the `channels is in [32, 64, 128]`,
inputs is[batch_size, channels, img_size, img_size]
and the `duration` of them as follows:

```
Channels: 32
Normal Conv 0.7769527435302734s, Sep Conv 1.4197885990142822s
Channels: 64
Normal Conv 0.8963277339935303s, Sep Conv 1.5703468322753906s
Channels: 128
Normal Conv 0.9741833209991455s, Sep Conv 1.665834665298462s
```

It seems that when batch_size is a constant only change channel the time cost of the normal one and the separable one is growing gradually.

And when setting `batch_size * channels` as a constant
Inputs shape as [CHANNELS_BATCH_SIZE // channels, channels, imgsize, imgsize]

```
Channels: 32
Normal Conv 0.871959924697876s, Sep Conv 1.569300651550293s
Channels: 64
Normal Conv 0.909860372543335s, Sep Conv 1.604109525680542s
Channels: 128
Normal Conv 0.9196009635925293s, Sep Conv 1.6144189834594727s
```

What confuses me is the result is different from the result of the link above: the time cost of sep_conv2d does not have obvious change.

My Questions are:

1. What makes it different between the link above and the experiment by myself?
2. I am a **newbie**, so is there something wrong in my code to implement the separable_conv2d?
3. How to implement the separable_conv2d can be faster than the normal one in **TF** or in **Pytorch**?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: Did you check the response of **sharvil**, on the link you shared? I guess, that will clarify your doubt.

Comment: @AnkishBansal Yes, I had checked sharvil's response. I think the experiment I did is similar to his, but the results are not expected, so I want to know what makes them different. Thanks for your response :D

Comment: @AnkishBansal Oh sorry my bro, I have made a mistake, I checked **kyle-dorman**'s response. I don't understand sharvil's main idea, I think his response didn't explain what the difference is between **sep_con2d** implemented in the link and implemented by tf library :/